# How to get email template name in system configuration?

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates

In module i have a custom email template.

my code in config.xml

```
<template>
            <email>
                <general_notification translate="label" module="example">
                    <label>Notifications</label>
                    <file>notification.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </general_notification>

            </email>
        </template>
```

Using this code i will get template name in system config

system.xml

```
    <notification>
    <label>Notification send to admin and customer</label>
        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>


        <source_model>example/email_notification</source_model>
            <sort_order>90</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>

    </notification>
```

In model

```
class NameSpace_Example_Model_Email_Notification
{
    protected $_options;

    public function toOptionArray(){
        return array(
            array('value' => '', 'label'=>Mage::helper('example')->__('Do not send')),
            array('value' => 'general_notification', 'label'=>Mage::helper('example')->__('New Notification(default template from locale)')),
        );
    }
}
```

Now In **System > Transaction Email** I m add New template and save that template So now i want this Email template name in system configuration how to get that please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you created email template you can get with below default code of magento `source model`

```
    <notification>
                <label>Select Email Template </label>
                <comment>It is advisable to create a new email template for this purpose and then select it in this configuration. Make sure you add review URL in your template. For e.g., {{ReviewURL}} <![CDATA[ <br /><span style="color:#FFA500">NOTE:- Default template from locale should not be used. Make sure you add product Name in your template. For e.g., {{ProductName}} You can also use other variables like OrderNumber {{OrderNumber}}</span>]]></comment>
                <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                <backend_model>mcautoreviewreminderemail/Mcautoreviewreminderemailtemplate</backend_model>
                <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_email_template</source_model>
                <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
   <notification>
```

i am sure it will work for you.

Comment: In backend_model what is 'mcautoreviewreminderemail' this. can you explain me? what should i write here?

Comment: you can ignore this, it was only for validation purpose for my used

Comment: Using this source model i can get template name but  email is empty there is no content display

Comment: `email` ? this source model will generate dropdown for available template insystem

Comment: you want Email template name in system configuration. thats given by above code.

Comment: u are right question only for get a name in dropdown your answer is ri8 but can you solve this problem?

Comment: you can ask another detail question.. and please accept and vote up it if its helpful to you.so it would be helpful to other as well.